# IFERROR then NA in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables are data and report.

The data table contains two columns: item and text. The item and text columns contain duplicates.

I am applying the following calculated column in the report table

```
RESULT =
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANK ( DATA[TEXT], TRUE () ),
    FILTER ( DATA, DATA[ITEM] = REPORT[ITEM] )
)
```

In order to get the data from the data table into the report table.

1. If the item is not available in the data table, then return “NA” according to the item in the report table. My calculated column is showing blanks if the item is not available in the data table but I want "NA" instead of blanks.
2. My calculated column is picking the min qty according to the item in the report table based on the data table where the same item contains multiple qty but I want max qty in the report table according to the item where the same item contains multiple qty.

Can you please advise?

Herewith attached the power bi for your reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3fa45f8qz8a2tm/LOOKUP%20MULTIPLE%20VALUE_QTY.pbix?dl=0

**Data & Report:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the max with just

```
RESULT = CALCULATE ( MAX ( DATA[TEXT] ) )
```

Replacing blanks with `NA` is possible but it means the `RESULT` column must be converted to a text data type (since a column cannot have multiple data types).

I don't advise doing that, but you can like this:

```
RESULT = 
VAR MaxText = CALCULATE ( MAX ( DATA[TEXT] ) )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( MaxText ), "NA", FORMAT ( MaxText, "0" ) )
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thank you so much for your help. it's very hard to reach you? Can an you please how can I reach you? like via LinkedIn or Facebook or twitter or email something like that.

Comment: It shouldn’t be hard to find me on LinkedIn but I’m not on any of the social media super frequently.

Comment: thank you. I will try to find out in LinkedIn. Can you please aspect my request.